# Dont know why this variable will not work

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently using

```
var hexArray = ["hexa", "hexb", "hexc", "hexd", "hexe", "hexf", "hexg", "hexh", "hexi", "hexj", "hexk", "hexl", "hexm"];

var burnArray = ["burna", "burnb", "burnc", "burnd", "burne", "burnf", "burng", "burnh", "burni", "burnj", "burnk", "burnl", "burnm"];

for(var i=0; i < hexArray.length; i++){
    document.getElementById(hexArray[i]).className='transtart ' + burnArray[i];
};
```

And this is working just fine, however when I change it to this:

```
var hexSelect = document.getElementById(hexArray[i]);

var hexArray = ["hexa", "hexb", "hexc", "hexd", "hexe", "hexf", "hexg", "hexh", "hexi", "hexj", "hexk", "hexl", "hexm"];

var burnArray = ["burna", "burnb", "burnc", "burnd", "burne", "burnf", "burng", "burnh", "burni", "burnj", "burnk", "burnl", "burnm"];

for(var i=0; i < hexArray.length; i++){
    hexSelect.className='transtart ' + burnArray[i];
};
```

It no longer works. And I have no idea why.

Comment: In your second example, what is `i` at the moment you are executing `var hexSelect = document.getElementById(hexArray[i]);`? Think about it.

Comment: `i` is not defined at the moment `hexArray[i]` is executed.

Comment: Applicative language semantics are apparently not obvious to people new to programming, which is not really surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your top line:

```
var hexSelect = document.getElementById(hexArray[i]);
```

It wont compile, because you use the i-variable from the for-loop.

Comment: Ahh okay, I wondered if it was my array call, is there any way to get around this at all?

Comment: @JSArrakis: Not really. Since the element that you want to get depends on the current iteration, you have to put that function call *in* the loop, just like your first code.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Ahh bummer, Im hoping to cut my code down as much as possible. Right now it kinda feels... larger than it needs to be. Note the bit I showed isnt all of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hexSelect = document.getElementById(hexArray[i]);

var hexArray = ["hexa", "hexb", "hexc", "hexd", "hexe", "hexf", "hexg", "hexh", "hexi", "hexj", "hexk", "hexl", "hexm"];

var burnArray = ["burna", "burnb", "burnc", "burnd", "burne", "burnf", "burng", "burnh", "burni", "burnj", "burnk", "burnl", "burnm"];

for(var i=0; i < hexArray.length; i++){
    hexSelect.className='transtart ' + burnArray[i];
};
```

In the first line of your code you are referencing the `hexArray` variable which at this point is `undefined`. The `i` variable at this point is also `undefined`.

To get your code working all you need to do is move your first line of code into the first line of the `for` loop below. Does that work?

Comment: Partly correct. The variable is actually declared (hoisting) but it doesn't have a value yet. However even if it was the other way round, it still wouldn't work.

Comment: And `i` isn't defined either.

Comment: Thanks guys, I made some edits. Googling "hoisting" ;)